How to Get Session Id for Front Door URL into Scratch Org via API?
After successfully creating a scratch org via API, I am now exploring ways to streamline admin access to this org. My goal is to create a URL that, when clicked, will automatically log the user into the scratch org. This URL should bypass the need for manual login credentials entry and would look like this:
(ScratchOrgInfo.LoginUrl)/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=(sessionId)
I'm looking for guidance on how to obtain a session ID that I can append to this URL right after creating the scratch org. Does anyone have experience or a script that can help with extracting or generating this session ID effectively via API?
Thank you for your insights!
